# Nokogiri : NoMethodError (undefined method `inner_html' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse a simple XML data with **nokogiri**.
this is my XML:

```
POST /.... HTTP/1.1
Host: ....
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://...."

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="...." xmlns:xsd="...." xmlns:soap="....">
  <soap:Body>
    <WS_QueryOnSec xmlns="......">
      <type>string</type>
      <ID>string</ID>
    </WS_QueryOnSec>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and this is my simle request:

```
require "nokogiri"
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(request.body.read)
@something = @doc.at('type').inner_html
```

But Nokogiri can not find the Type or ID node.
**When I change the data into this every thing works fine:**

```
  <soap:Body>
      <type>string</type>
      <ID>string</ID>
  </soap:Body>
```

It seems the problem is the *raw text above* the data and *the nods* with xmlns or the other attributes!
What do you recommend to resolve this ?

Comment: The first "XML" isn't XML. It's text that contains XML. Remove the header information down to the blank line. I think it'd help you to read the XML spec or to read some tutorials about creating XML.

Comment: @the Tin Man But what about the attributes included in those tags? When I remove the text it's still the same! Until I remove the whole tags containing attributes! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first "XML" isn't XML. It's text that contains XML. Remove the header information down to the blank line and try it again.

I think it'd help you to read the [XML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/) or to read some tutorials about creating XML which will help you understand how it's defined. XML is a tight specification and doesn't allow any deviation. The syntax is pretty flexible, but you have to play by its rules.

Consider these examples:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
foo

<root>
  <node />
</root>
EOT

doc.errors # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found>]
```

Removing the text, which is outside the root tag results in a proper parse:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<root>
  <node />
</root>
EOT

doc.errors # => []
```

`<root>` isn't neccesarily the name of the "root" node, it's just the outermost tag:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<foo>
  <node />
</foo>
EOT

doc.errors # => []
```

and still results in a valid DOM/internal representation of the document:

```
puts doc.to_html 

# >> <foo>
# >>   <node></node>
# >> </foo>
```

Your XML sample is using namespaces, which complicate matters somewhat. The [Nokogiri documentation](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#namespaces) talks about how to deal with them, so you'll want to understand that part of parsing XML because you'll encounter it again. Here's the easy way of working with them:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns:xsi="...." xmlns:xsd="...." xmlns:soap="....">
  <Body>
    <WS_QueryOnSec xmlns="......">
      <type>string</type>
      <ID>string</ID>
    </WS_QueryOnSec>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
EOT

namespaces = doc.collect_namespaces

doc.at('type', namespaces).text # => "string"
```

Comment: Thank you @theTinMan . It definitely can help knowing the structure.

Comment: By the way @the-tin-man is there any way to split text from xml in Nogokiri ?

Comment: It depends on what you call "text" and what your goals are. That'd really be a separate question but try messing around with `doc.search('//text()').map(&:text)` to get an idea of what you'll find. Usually you want something more surgical than that.